# Delete multiple records from table through cursor in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, azure-sql-database, cursors

there are number of test IP's which I would like to remove through system defined sp

exec sp_delete_firewall_rule from sys.firewall_rules table in sql server

I am using below cursor but its not working

```
declare @name nvarchar(max)

declare cur CURSOR LOCAL for

select @name from sys.firewall_rules where [name] like '%TestIP%'

open cur

fetch next from cur into @name

while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN

    exec sp_delete_firewall_rule  @name

    fetch next from cur into @name

END

close cur

deallocate cur
```

Comment: select name from sys.firewall_rules… vs.. select **@**name from sys.firewall_rules

Comment: @lptr it is still not working

Comment: is there any other option available to delete all records dynamically using the sp sp_delete_firewall_rule

Comment: have you checked the permissions  of sp_delete_firewall_rule? .. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-delete-firewall-rule-azure-sql-database?view=azure-sqldw-latest#permissions

Comment: .. you can check that the code does iterate through the set of rules by changing `exec sp_delete_firewall_rule  @name`… to … `select @name`

Comment: I have all the permissions

Comment: Can you please provide your code to check @lptr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked for me, you just need to change a couple of things in your code.

1. In the select list include the table **ColumnName [name] instead of variable**. You did not pass any value to the variable so this gives a NULL result.
2. Include SP parameter while executing **`exec sp_delete_firewall_rule @name = @name1;`**

I have these IP’s in my firewall rules:

[image]

With the below code I am deleting the IP’s which has a name like ***TestIP1***.

```
DECLARE @name1 nvarchar(128);
DECLARE MyCursor CURSOR FOR
  SELECT [name] from sys.firewall_rules where [name] like '%TestIP1%';
OPEN MyCursor;
FETCH FROM MyCursor into @name1
  WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN
    EXEC sp_delete_firewall_rule @name = @name1 ;
FETCH next from MyCursor into @name1
END
CLOSE MyCursor;
DEALLOCATE MyCursor;
GO
```

[image]

Now the result shows only 1 IP which is not included in the above delete list.

[image]